# How to make my layout able to scroll down?

Tags: android, layout

I can not scroll down the screen to view the data in the "Replied By:" section. How can I make my layout scrollable?

[image]

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Just wrap all that inside a `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Here you put the rest of your current view-->
</ScrollView>
```

As David Hedlund  said, `ScrollView`  can contain just one item... so if you had something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- bla bla bla-->
</LinearLayout>
```

You must change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!-- bla bla bla-->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: +1. a quick note: a `ScrollView` can only contain one child, so if what you've currently got is a lot of views, you need to wrap them in one view group (say a `LinearLayout`)

Comment: how to fix my problem please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588702/why-my-scrollview-not-working-properly

Answer (score 45):

For using scroll view along with Relative layout :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"> <!--IMPORTANT otherwise backgrnd img. will not fill the whole screen -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/background_image"
    >

    <!-- Bla Bla Bla i.e. Your Textviews/Buttons etc. -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What is the viewport tag

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap all that inside a ScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ruatech.sanikamal.justjava.MainActivity">
<!-- Here you put the rest of your current view-->
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very Simple. Just Put your Code Inside this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

//YOUR CODE

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you even did not get scroll after doing what is written above .....

Set the `android:layout_height="250dp"`or you can say `xdp` where `x` can be any numerical value.