# Scroll Down layout with Background image

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement scroll down layout with Background Image. I found a question about scroll down layout in android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819189/how-to-make-my-layout-able-to-scroll-down). So, how can I implement scroll down layout[Relative layout] with a background image. Thanks.

Comment: whats the problem...follow this answer that u have provide as link?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/background_image"
        >    
       </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```