# Make LinearLayout scrollable and preserve title bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development. I would like to make `LinearLayout` scrollable but after implementing the accepted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819189/how-to-make-my-layout-able-to-scroll-down), the default dark blue `ActionBar` at the top of my app disappeared. I am using `Empty Activity`.

Below is my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <!-- blah blah blah -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

There were no errors when I used this code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is this 'Empty Activity'? And do you mean actionbar is not visible?

Comment: `Empty Activity` is the activity I chose to use when I first start a new project in Android Studio. Basically just a pre-coded action bar (yes I think that's it, will update post now) for you. By action bar not visible please refer to my screenshot above.

Comment: Post your style.xml here - which was generated by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had finally figured out my problem. The reason why `Actionbar` is missing is because `ScrollView` was placed outside `LinearLayout`. To fix this, use another `LinearLayout` to wrap the `ScrollView`, as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <!-- Blah blah blah -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks to everyone, especially @arvicx, for their time! :)

I hope everyone who had this problem find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Open your styles.xml file under res/values/styles.xml and make sure that the AppTheme parent is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

and one thing, LinearLayout's attribute

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

should be

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Hope it helps... Tell me if it works.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the screen you have? and if you are referring to the title bar as actionbar/toolbar? right?

Comment: Yes and I had just posted the screenshot above

Comment: I'm sorry, both links can't be viewed. and I don't know why. Maybe country restrictions...

Comment: Try again now, I've set security to the minimum. Should be working :)

Comment: still nothing bro... webpage is not available... If my answer is still not working. you can try to change the MainActivity to extend Activity instead of AppCompatActivity but not a good solution and just a workaround, there are also only certain versions of Android that shows the ActionBar. The best one is to implement your own toolbar as what @FranMowinckel said.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time though. Link is `yikjin.ga/Capture.PNG`, if it is not working means its a country restriction. I will try and implement my own toolbar

Comment: Good thing. Because that's the standard way to do it now... Goodluck and have fun bro. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Toolbar` support class instead as described in [Setting Up the App Bar](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/appbar/setting-up.html). The reason is (as described in the link) the `ActionBar` behaves differently depending on what version of Android is used.

Apart from that, @arvicx is correct, the layout height of the `LinearLayout` should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` because it doesn't make sense to have a scrollable element the same size as its container.

And you also might want to add `android:fillViewport="true"` for the reasons described [here](http://www.curious-creature.com/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Answer (score 0):

Buddy,

Use LinearLayout vertically to put your title bar and scrollview respectively.

Comment: I assume it means in `LinearLayout` I have to use `android:orientation="vertical"`? If that's so, I've already done it in the code above.

Comment: You need to move your titlebar out of scrollview. And packed them together into another LinearLayout which had its orientation set to vertical.